# How to add files to build and read them in Code Blocks?

Tags: c++, winapi, codeblocks

I want to write only-exe application and I must load an image. What I have to do?

Project Manager: https://dawidsk.gamejolt.io/images/ScreenShot_20190727141153.png

(Sorry for bad English)

Loading image code:

```cpp
void AddControls(HWND hWnd)
{
    hWarning = CreateWindowW(L"Static", NULL, WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | SS_BITMAP, 0, 0, windowHeight, windowWidth, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    SendMessageW(hWarning, STM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP,(LPARAM) hWarningImage);
}

void LoadImages()
{
    hWarningImage = (HBITMAP)LoadImageW(NULL, L"warning.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, windowHeight, windowWidth, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
}
```

When I remove warning.bmp from root folder of exe, it's not displaying it.

EDIT:
Now I know that I must use resource.rc. How can I load image from it?

Comment: LoadImages and AddControls are called from WM_CREATE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow this document to load it:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/bitmap-resource

syntax:

```
nameID BITMAP "warning.bmp"
```

EDIT:

After this, you could load the bitmap **with the instance**.

define your nameID with a value, such as

```
#define nameID 40001
```

Then loadimage with nameID and **instance handle**, remove the `LR_LOADFROMFILE`:

```
LoadImageW(hInstance,MAKEINTRESOURCE(nameID),IMAGE_BITMAP, windowHeight, windowWidth, 0);
```

Comment: then how I can load it with LoadImageW()?

Comment: @dawidsk12345 First `#define nameID (somevalue such as 40001 which <65535)`, then `LoadImageW(NULL,MAKEINTRESOURCE(nameID),IMAGE_BITMAP, windowHeight, windowWidth, 0);`